# Problems adding arrays into an arrayllist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have  these two classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Giocatore {
private String nome;
private ArrayList<Cartella> cartelle;

public Giocatore(String nome, int numeroCartelle) {
    this.nome = nome;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroCartelle; i++) {
        cartelle.add(new Cartella().creazioneCartella());
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Giocatore" + " nome=" + nome + ", cartelle=" + cartelle + "]";
}

}
```

and

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Cartella {
private int[] cartella;

public Cartella() {
    cartella = new int[15];
}


public int[] creazioneCartella() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int n = random.nextInt(90 + 1) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartella.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (n == cartella[j]) {
                    n = random.nextInt(90 + 1) + 1;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        cartella[i] = n;
    }
    return cartella;
}

public void stampaCartella() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cartella.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(cartella[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public int[] getCartella() {
    return cartella;
}

public void setCartella(int[] cartella) {
    this.cartella = cartella;
}
}
```

i used the class Cartella as an arraylist in Giocatore, now i want to add an array into that arraylist using the method creazioneCartella(), but every time the compiler suggest me to change the method creazioneCartella into an element of Cartella. How can i add that array into that list? i've tried different methods like Arrays.asList(array) but nothing

Comment: Did you want to store `Cartella` or did you want to store `int[]` in your `ArrayList<Cartella> cartelle`?

Comment: i would store the int[] created in creazioneCartella() in  ArrayList<Cartella> cartelle

Comment: That will never happen. You can store `int[]` in an `ArrayList<int[]>` or you can store `Cartella` in an `ArrayList<Cartella>`.